# How to show human-readable "time ago"

Tags: javascript, jquery

My user last logged in  at 15:50:09 Wednesday, January 25, 2012 IST 
how can i show it as "10 minutes ago".
Is there any js?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have always used [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/), it is a jQuery plugin, very easy to use.  The example in the main page is self-explicative:

```
<script src="jquery.timeago.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
$("abbr.timeago").timeago();
```

Will convert this markup:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2008-07-17T09:24:17Z">July 17, 2008</abbr>
```

into this one:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="July 17, 2008">3 years ago</abbr>
```

In some cases is useful to also use [datejs](http://www.datejs.com/), specially if you want to convert dates in a human readable format to a timestamp, but in your case I don't think you really need it.