# Working with Jquery timeago plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

I am working with [Timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin.

What can I do in order to us this kind of timestamp `2012-03-14 22:17:48?`

Also

Javascript new `Date()` gives me `Thu Mar 14 2012 23:24:51 GMT-0600 (MDT)` which is my correct time.

I have the following for Timeage:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2012-03-14T22:17:48Z"></abbr>
```

Yet it is telling me it was posted "a day ago", which is actually about an hour and 7 minutes... What could be going wrong?

Comment: try easy date it works better

Comment: It will help u
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001193/how-to-show-human-readable-time-ago

Answer (score 5):

I used easy date it works great
 add script **easydate-0.2.4.js**
 then include

```
<abbr class="easydate">
   @Model.LastseenDate 
</abbr>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks alot for answer and link! I modified the question, due to some issuess I was having.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Livestamp.js](http://mattbradley.github.com/livestampjs/), you can do something like this:

```
<abbr class="livestamp"></abbr>
<script>
    $('.livestamp').livestamp(new Date('2012-03-14 22:17:48'));
</script>
```